# Descriptions across the scale in corrplot()

Tags: r

Is any way how to move labels put over scale in `corrplot`?

[image]

Comment: Did you try adjusting `corrplot`'s arguments `tl.offset` and `cl.offset`? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/corrplot/versions/0.92/topics/corrplot

Comment: @I_O I did. But thanks for link. `cl.align.text = "l"` works!

Comment: chromanna if @I_O's hint served you to solve the problem, please consider writing it _as an answer_ (giving appropriate credit for the helpful comment). That way it may help other people who may face the same problem in the future.